# Is there a list of unsupported APIs for UWP?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, uwp, windows-store-apps

Recently, I started integration of an existing project (multiplatform project) to `UWP`. The main issue is, that `UWP` has not all of the libraries and APIs the standard Windows API provides. But also there's no article or documentation to check whether this or that functionality is supported. I wonder whether I have skipped any of them. If not, any hint to ensure the lib is not supported for `UWP` and/or find an alternative to it?

Comment: This is going to get closed as off-topic. The off-site resource you're looking for is [Win32 and COM APIs for UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps).

Comment: The in/out decision is by API, not library. For example, some functions from kernel32.lib are in, but others are out. The documentation for each API says whether it is desktop-only, UWP-only, or both, at the bottom under "Minimum supported client".

Comment: @RaymondChen the problem is that doc doesn't tell anything. Or maybe I missed something. I will bring an example of a function tommorow

Comment: Can you please provide an example of some functions you currently used?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT They are used by 3rd party libs that I had to link to. A fresh example is the `CreateFile` function.

Comment: Are you referring to [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#requirements) function? If it is, you can check the **Requirements** part, it only supports desktop apps, it can't support uwp apps. If you want to open or create a file in uwp, you can use [StorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile?view=winrt-19041) class.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT First, thanks for your support. Second, I have already found the class in another question in SO but it seems that class is `C#` class, isn't it? If it isn't, then maybe you could provide a brief example of `C++` code using `StorageFile` class? Few more notes. I try to compile `WebRTC` lib for `UWP` and also have problems with `timeGetTime()` function - in case you can help with this one as well.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT what about `CreateFile2`? Is this the analog for `CreateFile` for UWP?

Comment: Yeap, you can use the StorageFile class in uwp to create or get file, ect. In addition, are you referring to [timeGetTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timegettime) function? It also only supports the desktop apps, but not uwp apps. You can't use this function in uwp.